# Content Editor Web Part Blocked Me Out

Tags: content, web

I was working on updating my department's Sharepoint site. While in Edit mode, I clicked on a link titled "Add a Web Part" and began looking at the different Web Parts to add. When I clicked on a blank one, I was unsure of what it would do, so I did not click add, I closed the screen with the "x" button thinking it would not save.  I was wrong. After closing the screen and opening back up the page, all I see is is a bar saying "Content Editor Web Part" and I cannot access any of the links above to edit the page.  Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `?contents=1` to your URL (e.g. `http://yoursite/sitepages/home.aspx?contents=1`).

That will take you to the web part maintenance page where you can delete the web part that you just accidentally added.

Comment: Another URL option is ?PageView=Shared&ToolPaneView=2. The reason this happens is because when you add a web part to a page sometimes SharePoint renders the page differently. This is especially important if you are adding a Content Editor Web Part to a list view.